# I can replicate an entity keeping the original id in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I need to persist an object with the [replicate method of hibernate's session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#replicate%28java.lang.Object,%20org.hibernate.ReplicationMode%29), but i want the object to retain its id, because it's an identity column in SQL Server.

Any idea as to how to achieve this?

I tried to manipulate the generator, but that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Replicate method should already be keeping id. If you want its children to retain id you must configure cascading to cascade on replicate.